# What is the storage best to use in azure where my requirement is to show records/logs able to delete if size of records is more than some MB

Tags: azure, storage

I need suggestion which Storage account to use in Azure.
I have requirement to store logs/records which will be dispalyed in UI in a tabular manner with properties.I should be able to search/sort/Filter.
I have option for cosmosDb,Table storage but I have another requirement whenever records size will be more than 50 MB,then delete old records.

Which one i should use to handle above all requirements.

Comment: What are these logs? What is the volume i.e. GB's of these logs? What is the retention policies of such log data?

Comment: Log is the entity class where it will be formed from custom event and stored in DB.There is no retention policy as such .Requirement is need to check on daily basis if the records size is more than 50 MB just delete those old records.

Comment: This seems to be a case of temporal storage (Azure Files - managed NFS mounts) like you have mentioned that the logging entity anyways gets published in a database of choice such as Azure SQL database which will allow for any or all standard SQL functions related to sorting and searching.

Comment: Why not use Azure Monitor?